# In Vue how do I replace array with new array?

Tags: vue.js

Every 10 seconds I query my database for latest fire calls. I do `app.events = data.calls` but my data doesn't refresh. I initialize the data with the same function that is called every 10 seconds. I see the table. How I do I replace an array in Vue with an array?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
          $('#demo').text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
      $.get('http://localhost:8000/api/nearest_events?lng='+position.coords.longitude+'&lat='+position.coords.latitude, function(data) {
        //app.$set(app.events, Object.assign({}, app.events, data.calls));
        app.events = data.calls;
      })
    }
app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    events: []
  },
  created: function() {
    setInterval(getLocation(), 10000)
  }
})
  })

</script>
<style>
td, th {border:1px solid #000;padding:5px}
table { border-collapse:collapse;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
<table>
  <tr v-for="event in events">
    <td>{{ event.datetime }}</td>
    <td>{{ event.address }}</td>
    <td>{{ event.type }}</td>
    <td>
<table>
<tr><th>Unit</th><th>Dispatched at</th><th>Arrived at</th><th>In service</th></tr>
<tr v-for="unit in event.units">
<td>{{ unit.unit }}</td>
<td>{{ unit.dispatched }}</td>
<td>{{ unit.arrived }}</td>
<td>{{ unit.in_service }}</td>
</tr>
</table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your problem is in `setInterval`.  When you call `getLocation` it does not require the `()`

```
i = 0;
app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    events: []
  },
  methods: {
    getLocation: function () {
      var self = this;
      i+=1;
      self.events =  [1,2,3,i];
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    self = this;
    setInterval(self.getLocation, 1000);
  }
})
```

And here is a working demo:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/EwLVNB

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it. See https://codepen.io/policevideorequests/pen/GMdpZr where the last block only updates to 1 not 2,3,4,etc

Comment: Ah I see what you are looking for.  Yes, still is working correctly, you just need to update your setInterval.  I have updated my answer.  Also view at https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/EwLVNB

Comment: Try `setInterval(self.getLocation, 1000);`. Vue binds `this` for methods.

Comment: Also, it works fine to update the data from outside the Vue.